# What color should a disabled link be set according to the standards?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What is the standard color for a disabled link (anchor tag) according to the standards ?

Comment: no such thing really, but it would be black probably.

Comment: light grey is pretty typical in my experience. Looking at stack overflow style sheet they go for `color: #888;opacity: 0.6;filter: alpha(opacity=60);`

Comment: It would be helpful if the down voters leave a comment. I am just trying to know something here. SO is not only for great questions from great programmers. Its for beginners too.

Comment: @Ebenezar I didn't down vote but I still don't like your question. Have you actually read the "about" page, which tells how to make good questions and what not to do?

Comment: @BoltClock edited. Thank you for pointing out. Will keep in mind.

Comment: I do believe most browsers use that blue to purple scheme for links by default? Not sure what relation that kind of purple has to that kind of blue. But maybe there is a theory behind it?

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of_ **detailed answers to every question about programming.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard. It should harmonize with the design of the whole page.
I prefere just less color intensity.

For example you have a link with the color `rgb(186,3,23)`. Then change it to `rgba` and add a opacity to the link.
So in my example the disabled link would be `rgba(186,3,23,0.5)`.

Or if you use hex-color code, then add `opacity`:

```
/* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
/* ...but not required as filter works too */
/* should come BEFORE filter */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
/* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);

/* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
-moz-opacity:0.5;

/* Modern!
/* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
/* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
opacity: 0.5;
```

If you won't use `opacity`, use just a brighter color of your normal link color. To find out a good bright color of another color, use [Color Scheme Designer 3](http://colorschemedesigner.com/).
So for the hex-color code `#BA0317` the brighter version would be `#DD6573`

Comment: The Netscape and Safari lines aren't needed.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on your page design. There nothing called standard in this regard. If your page is having link in 'red'(like oracle.com) color then it should me something based on that color.

Define whichever color is appropriate in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If “disabled link (anchor tag)” means an `a` element with `href` attribute but somehow in a disabled state, then there is no standard, because such an element is not described in standards or even in standards-like drafts. You can disable a link e.g. by adding event handlers that prevent normal ways of following the link, but this is not an HTML or CSS concept and has no default styling (as different from normal links) recommended.

If it means an `a` element that lacks the `href` attribute, then it is not regarded as a link at all in styling (as per specifications or browser practices). This means that its default color is the same as for normal elements, namely that it inherits color from its parent. With no color settings in the chain from the element to the `body` element, the browser default color, mostly black, is used.

If you meant to ask what you should set as color, or about “design standards”, then it’s a completely different question and basically an opinion poll, hence unsuitable for SO.